# dnf breaks when changing symlink from python3.9 to 3.10

Tags: fedora, python, dnf

I am completely baffled.
on Fedora34  and python 3.9.7 dnf works as it should.

I have changed to the /usr/bin directory for this.

If I change the symlink to 3.10 as in the following, dnf breaks:

```
➜  bin ln -s -f python3.10 python3
➜  bin dnf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 57, in <module>
    from dnf.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dnf'
```

Then I change it back to 3.9 and dnf works.

```
➜  bin ln -s -f python3.9 python3   
➜  bin dnf
usage: dnf [options] COMMAND
etc...
```

Can someone explain this to me and how to update the system so that having the python3 command point to 3.10 without breaking dnf?

Answer (score 12):

Don't do that: if you want to use different version of Python for your projects or development you need to either use the versioned command `python3.x` or [virtual environments](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/).

System tools like DNF depend on the exact Python ABI version. On Fedora 34 you have the Python 3.9 version of Python DNF installed in `/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages` and it won't work with Python 3.10 without recompiling it with the newer Python:

```
$ rpm -q --requires python3-dnf
/usr/bin/python3
...
python(abi) = 3.9
```

If you really want Python 3.10 system-wide, you can [upgrade](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/dnf-system-upgrade/) to Fedora 35 which ships Python 3.10 by default. (Fedora 35 is not released yet, but it's already gone through beta so it should be stable enough.)

Comment: Thank you. I'll go with virtual environments